# Q: Need advice on how to approach development on Jenkins metric capturing program (Jenkins Rest API, Groovy, etc)

Tags: json, rest, groovy, jenkins

I have been tasked to make a program that will pull relevant metric data from Jenkins. I only have a week to get myself up to speed with everything that this program will need, and I'm also not the best of a programmer to start. With that said, I would love some advice from the more seasoned developers that have used the Jenkins REST API and scripting languages (Groovy, Python, etc) to pull metric data from Jenkins.

OVERVIEW: The end goal of the program is to display some metrics that are preserved in Jenkins which will give a better idea of how the build deploying / tests have been going. This will give my business some insight into tracking tests and the build deploy processes in a trend. These metrics include but are not limited to: How many tests have failed/passed/skipped, Build execution time, Percentage of passed builds vs failed builds, etc...

I've consolidated all the info you might need about the program below, but here are the biggest questions that I have for this program:

- Is it even possible to learn all this and apply it in a matter of a week? (account for the fact that I possess 0 level of familiarity with any of the relevant technologies). Don't get me wrong, if it's possible, I will work towards making this work, but if it isn't possible even from a seasoned developer's perspective, what's the point?
- I looked into Jenkins plugin development and for my purpose, it doesn't seem that a plugin is what I want. Am I correct in assuming so?

Anyway, here's all my research, conflicts, and questions on going about developing this program:

1) After some research, I've learned that I can access the metrics that I need through Jenkins' REST API. However, there does not seem to be much documentation or tutorials that show how I can connect to the API and actually use it to pull the data that I want (keep in mind, this is my first time hearing about a REST API, so it's fairly new to me; I followed some examples that use different APIs but I'm having a hard time applying them to the Jenkins API. if someone could explain this and in specifics to the Jenkins API that would be much appreciated).

I also know that this step will include programming via a scripting language such as Groovy or Python to query the Jenkins and retrieve the JSON, but I'm unfamiliar with both languages and on how I should go about using them at all. Does anyone have any resources that are good to teach me what I'll need to know just for the purposes of this program? Could I code this program in another language like JS or Java?

Next- I know the step that follows in this is to somehow parse the JSON format into something that I can use and display, but again--with no experience in using REST APIs or the scripting languages, I'm very lost. I'm not even sure how to manipulate the link to filter on the fields that I specifically want either (e.g. I saw that some people use the convention of `tree=builds... etc` at the end of the API link, but I don't know where they learned that this was even possible... where is this documented? I can't even simply get the link to filter on the things that I want to see..). I imagine this step is as simple as looking up some sort of JSON parsing method, but I can't say for certain.

2) Once I have retrieved the JSON format and parsed the info that I want, I need to write it to a file (most likely CSV-Comma Separated Value) format that can be easily imported into Excel. I don't know how to proceed with this step at all.. From what I've researched though, apparently this isn't a step that I should worry about, as there are bound to be Groovy packages that deal with this (whatever that even means... a coworker had just told me this and wrote it off assuming that I'd be able to figure it out, but I honestly don't know what he meant at all). How would I go about finding a package that matches what I need? (Or am I even correct in trusting that packages exist for this purpose?)

3) Because this data needs to persist over time, I'll likely need to find a way to save it to a file or database that can be updated each time the script is run. This by far is one of the most confusing steps in the process that I don't know how to go about at all. Am I supposed to set up some database somewhere on my own or ask for database space somewhere in the company? How would I go about saving it to a file each time the script was run? If I understand this correctly, would this mean that someone would need to manually execute my program each time to update it? How would I go about automating this process?

I feel like I'm drinking from a firehose here and need as much help as I can get. Thank for taking the time to read my long post, and I appreciate any and all help!

Answer (score 2):

an interesting project and I feel that you are on the right track.

> Is it even possible to learn all this and apply it in a matter of a week?

hm. I guess it depends on the quality of the result. But I also feel that you've already done a good job by researching the problem. You should make clear that your result will be the start of a solution and you should document your solution and decisions (the same way you did above) so that some one else can pick up your work. But don't give up!

> I looked into Jenkins plugin development and for my purpose, it doesn't seem that a plugin is what I want. Am I correct in assuming so?

I think so, too. The Rest-API approach sounds resonable.

> Could I code this program in another language like JS or Java?

Yes, afaik, nearly any language could be used. But Groovy is a good choice for this kind of problem. And aprox. 95% of Java Code is Groovy Code... So you can use your Java knowledge to write Groovy and throw in some Groovy shortcuts. Maybe you should take a look at these slides: http://de.slideshare.net/KostasSaidis/an-introduction-to-groovy-for-java-developers

> REST

You might want to take a look at a project like this one: https://github.com/rdmueller/asciidoc2confluence . It uses the confluence REST API and might be a starting point...

> Database and Display

Now when it comes to make the collected data persistent and display them on some kind of dashboard, I think your ideas to use excel are great for a first prototype.
It makes sense to first write the collected data to as CSV file which can be later visualized through excel.

However, this might not the preferred solution for a good application since it does not solve problems like access control and others.

But when you start out with a Groovy script, you can easily turn it later into a Grails application... probably not this week, but a framework like Grails will give you a database out of the box and enough options for a cool looking dashboard :-)

But back to my initial advice: you started out great by asking yourself the right questions and seeking advice. Even if you don't manage to come up with a working prototype this week, you will have learned a lot and also created value by documenting your decisions...

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for making sure that I'm on the right track. I've changed some of my logic around and have chosen to go with saving the necessary metric data in a database that can be interfaced later. I'm struggling a bit on pulling the right data from the REST-API link due to authentication issues though.. will start a thread to explore solutions

Comment: have you seen this jenkins authentication example? https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Authenticating+scripted+clients . It even comes with a Groovy script!